# What is this odd character?

Tags: orthography, kana

[image: Character]

It foiled 3 different online handwriting input websites. I tried looking it up via radicals to no avail. The rest of the characters in this font were quite easy to get.

As per request, the context.
[image: Context]

I had decided on "ざ"

Comment: Hiragana そ has variations (like Latin lowercase "g" and "a" have typographical variations). [See this](http://ameblo.jp/juku1974/entry-11128623281.html).

Comment: I always write the two-stroke version of そ, and since that is how I was taught the character, I believe there are a number of Japanese who still write it that way as well. But, my understanding is that it's a more old-fashioned way to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for adding the context. It is indeed ぞ. The whole thing is:

まほはまにゅうのまぞしょうじょ.

EDIT: Looking for more context I tried to google it and it seems the title of some kind of erotic anime or manga? That was kinda embarrassing since I'm at work and a quite inappropriate picture came out. Lol :)

Comment: Sorry about that, perhaps I should have given some warning. I was a little unsure about posting it here, weird tastes and all that.

Any indication for why it looks so different?

Is there a place where I could look at this character in more fonts?

Comment: How about this: http://www.utf8icons.com/character/12382/hiragana-letter-zo

Comment: You get to answer questions here while at work? ;)

Comment: Well, given that I work at least 10 hours a day I allow myself a little break once in a while. :D
..And although I'm in an open space my seat is quite saf...speak of the devil my boss just showed up. But I guess why someone created alt+space+n. Lol

Answer (score 2):

It would be must easier if you gave more context but off of just this I would just guess ぞ (zo).

Comment: I was exactly thinking about ぞ too and I was waiting for more context indeed.

Comment: I added context.